Link between mean curvature and divergence
I'm starting to learn differential geometry, and I have a question. I'm reading an article where they state that given a surface $S$ embeded in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and a vector field $\mathbf{v}$ defined on $S$, one can decomposes the divergence of $\mathbf{v}$ as:
$\bar{div}(\mathbf{v_{||}})+ \mathbf{v_n}H$, where $\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{v_{||}}+v_n \mathbf{n}$ is decompoed in its tangential and normal component to $S$, $\bar{div}$ is the covariant divergence, and $H$ the mean curvature. Can someone maybe explains me, or give me some references, how do they obtain this formula?
Thanks you!

This is related

This is a reasonable exercise for someone learning differential geometry. Have you learned the definitions of divergence, second fundamental form, mean curvature? If so, you should start with them. You can edit your post to show how far you can get. We can then offer advice on how to proceed.
